# Search and remove an element in mulit-dimentional array in php depending on a criteria

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I've a simple question about multi-dim array, I want to remove any redundent element let's say in my case, `[serviceMethod] => PL` is coming 2 times, I want to search 'PL' with respect of `[APIPriceTax]` if an element has a lower price I want to keep it and remove the other one in array

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
                   [carrierIDs] => 150
                   [serviceMethod] => CP
                   [APIPriceTax] =>  30.63 
                   [APIPriceWithOutTax]  28.32 
                   [APIServiceName] =>  Xpresspost USA 
                   [APIExpectedTransitDay]  => 2 
               )
    [1] => Array (
                    [carrierIDs] => 155
                    [serviceMethod] => PL
                    [APIPriceTax] => 84.13
                    [APIPriceWithOutTax] => 73.8
                    [APIServiceName] => PurolatorExpressU.S.
                    [APIExpectedTransitDay] => 1
               )
  [2] => Array (
                    [carrierIDs] => 164
                    [serviceMethod] => PL
                    [APIPriceTax] => 25.48
                    [APIPriceWithOutTax] => 22.35
                    [APIServiceName] => PurolatorGroundU.S.
                    [APIExpectedTransitDay] => 3
                  )
```

)

This is my pseudo code: Where `$carrierAddedToList` is the actual array

```
$newCarrierAry = function($carrierAddedToList)
  { 
   $newArray = array(); 
   foreach($carrierAddedToList as $cV => $cK) 
   { 
    if( !in_array($cK['serviceMethod'],$newArray) ) 
     { 
       array_push($newArray, $cK['serviceMethod']); 
     } 

   } 
    return $newArray;
 } ; 
  print_r($newCarrierAry($carrierAddedToList));
```

Comment: What's the question you have about this?

Comment: You could try it in a way similar to what I suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19423074/skipping-a-multidimensional-array-in-a-foreach-loop-php/19423354#19423354

Comment: Why does `APIPriceTax` sometimes point to a `SimpleXMLElement` object, and other times just point to a number?

Comment: @Barmar, I wanted to search in array that everytime array produce 2 elements depending on [serviceMethod], if there are more than 2 element in array then code will check if there's any repetitive element then remove only higher [APIPriceTax]

Comment: I understand what you want to do. You said you had a simple question about arrays, but never asked a question, just described what you want to achieve. We're not here to write your code for you, we're here to help you fix the problems in your code. So post what you've tried and we'll help you get it working.

Comment: Cool Down @Barmar, I updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there's no `in_array()` that searches multi-dimensional elements, build an associative array that's keyed by the serviceMethod. Then you can use `isset()` to check whether we already have an element with that method.

```
$newArray = array();
foreach ($carrierAddedToList as $cK) {
    $sm = $cK['serviceMethod'];
    if (!isset($newArray[$sm]) || $newArray[$sm]['APIPriceTax'] > $cK['ApiPriceTax']) {
        $newArray[$sm] = $cK;
    }
}
// Now convert associative array to indexed:
$newArray = array_values($newArray);
```